# How to inject HttpRequestBase and HttpContextBase in Funq (while using ServiceStack)

Tags: servicestack, funq

I have been happily using AutoFaq for a couple of years and take advantage of its ability to easily inject HttpRequestBase and HttpContextBase in the MVC pipeline.  This makes mocking and decoupling a lot easier.

I am in the process of changing my data layer to ServiceStack and as part of wiring the default Funq DI mechanism to my different layers I can't figure out how to inject HttpRequestBase and HttpContextBase.

Is there a way to do this?  I am looking for the container.Register() analog inside of AppHost.Configure(Func.Container container).

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ServiceStack doesn't allow registering runtime dependencies with its IOC, although as ServiceStack Services and [Request pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Order-of-Operations) only binds to the [IRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequest.cs) interface which can just inject a mocked [IRequest](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Web/IRequest.cs) directly on the service when its required, e.g:

```
var service = new MyService {
    Request = new MockHttpRequest()
};

var response = service.Get(new MyRequest { Id = 1 });
```

The [Testing wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Testing) shows other ways of testing ServiceStack services.

Answer (score 0):

ServiceStack has it's own abstraction of the HttpContext and Request/Response. In v3.x, these are IRequestContext, IHttpRequest, IHttpResponse. This is to be implementation-independent of ASP.NET ([console](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Self-hosting) or [Mono](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Mono)). It is recommended you use the abstractions instead of trying to use the underlying ASP.NET objects.

In your Service code, you may access them this way:

```
var httpReq = base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
var httpResp = base.RequestContext.Get<IHttpResponse>();
```

If you really need the real ASP.NET HttpContext, [apparently you should be able to access it at IRequest.OriginalRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674263/how-to-get-httpcontext-in-servicestack-net). But if you are trying it the ServiceStack way, "don't do that".

More explanation of the Funq usage in v3 is here:
https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/The-IoC-container